# How to trigger mousemove event only when mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mousemove, onmousemove

In my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rgEp6/9/)  event trigger even when the mouse is not moving but is inside the container.

```
var page = $('.Page'),
    consoleContainer = $('.Console');

page.mousemove(null, function(e){
    var mousePosX = (e.pageX/$(window).width())*100;
    consoleContainer.val('mousePos: ' + mousePosX + ' randomNumber: ' + Math.random());
});
```

**that I want:**
if mouse does not move but inside the container the event shouldn't work

PS: Sorry for my english skill

Comment: If you put the cursor inside the gray area and refresh the page... The event is **not** triggered. What you want exactly?

Comment: random number is still generated after refresh, even cursor inside the gray area

Comment: you're right, but you should mention that that's the case for Chrome only.

Comment: Oh...
Thank you @RokoC.Buljan.
I think the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the previous cursor position and when the mousemove event is fired check if it's equal than current mouse position.

Something like this should work as expected:

```
var page = $('.Page'), consoleContainer = $('.Console');
var prevPos = '';

page.mousemove(null, function(e)
{
    var currPos = e.pageX + '-' + e.pageY;

    if (prevPos != currPos)
    {
        prevPos = currPos;
        var mousePosX = (e.pageX / $(window).width()) * 100;
        consoleContainer.val('mousePos: ' + mousePosX + ' randomNumber: ' + Math.random());
    }
});
```

Comment: i don't know what's happend, but my code didn't work on my workmachine.
Now i'm tested it at home - all ok.
It's just bug or smth i don't know.

Comment: Are you testing with the same browser (same version too)?